# Reading CSV file with different row length in java

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I try to read all the lines from a CSV file, but not all the lines are the same length. I used this code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://Users/Balazs/Downloads/numbers.csv"));
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] szamok = line.split(";");
```

But if some rows are longer than the ones before, it gives me error. 
Any ideas how to solve this in java?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that happens because of the length of the line, but rather because of its content. Could you add an int variable that tells you at which lane did the program throws the error? Also could you please clarify what error appears?

Comment: A csv file normally is comma delimited, are you sure you want to split on `;` and not `,`?

Comment: I tried to use this:
  if (szamok[19]!=null) {
                    Integer hetedikSzam = Integer.parseInt(szamok[19]);
                
                hetedikSzam = Integer.parseInt(szamok[19]);
                }

but it gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Most of the lines ends at szamok[18], but there are some in szamok[19]

Comment: Please do **not** put code in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Comment: You should better check  `if(szamok.length >18)` instead of `if (szamok[19]!=null)`

Comment: Nope, still gives me the same error message

Comment: My mistake: it should be 19 not 18  `if(szamok.length >19)`

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved :)

Comment: Post your final solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

if (szamok.length > 19) {
                    Integer hetedikSzam = Integer.parseInt(szamok[19]);

```
            hetedikSzam = Integer.parseInt(szamok[19]);
             }
```